# How to validate a Date (using a calendar)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a website in C#, with a calendar, like this:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="DataCalendar" runat="server" SelectionMode="DayWeekMonth" SelectedDate="01-01-2000 00:00:00"></asp:Calendar>
```

How can I validade this? To make the user select a date.
And how can I make user change the date, by changing year? Because this way the user can only change date by month... I it would not be easy when you want to change a few years....

I have this in the `.cs` file:

```
DateTime date1 = DataCalendar.SelectedDate;
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(01, 01, 2000, 00, 00, 00); //starting time no choose

int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);

if (result == 0)
{
    FailureText.Text = "Choose a Date!";
    ErrorMessage.Visible = true;

    return;
}
```

Comment: Please write the smallest code possible which is not working. We can't do your homework for you.

Comment: Remove `SelectionMode` and `SelectedDate` properties.  Add a [validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx).  Most importantly, read about the [calendar control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx).